# Matplotlib show one axis and no data

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I want to show just the x axis for a figure and have another figure below plotting the data (the lower one with the same x axis values as to top plot but not showing any ticks or labels).

I haven't seen any documentation of changing the actual plot dimensions, only the figure dimensions.

The code below gives some idea, but I want the top plot to show just a horizontal line and x values, the y axis should have no dimension. By setting subplots_adjust I can get the y axis as close as I can to zero, but setting bottom any larget (bottom=0.9 I get a ValueError(bottom cannot be >= top)

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QSizePolicy
import sys

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

qapp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
qWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
qWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 400))
hBoxLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(qWidget)
qWidget.setLayout(hBoxLayout)

qScroll = QtGui.QScrollArea(qWidget)
qScroll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 400))
qScroll.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.NoFrame)
qScroll.setVisible(True)
hBoxLayout.addWidget(qScroll)

qScrollContents = QtGui.QWidget()
qScrollLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(qScrollContents)
qScrollLayout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 800))

qScroll.setWidget(qScrollContents)
qScroll.setWidgetResizable(True)

qFigWidget1 = QtGui.QWidget(qScrollContents)
fig1 = Figure(figsize=(5.0, 1.0), dpi=100)
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig1)
canvas.setParent(qFigWidget1)
canvas.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
x = np.arange(0, 10.0, 0.1)
yData = np.zeros(100)  
ax1.plot(x, yData)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 0)
ax1.get_xaxis().tick_bottom() 
ax1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
fig1.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.85)

plotLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
plotLayout.addWidget(canvas)
qFigWidget1.setLayout(plotLayout)
qScrollLayout.addWidget(qFigWidget1)

qFigWidget2 = QtGui.QWidget(qScrollContents)
fig2 = Figure(figsize=(5.0, 5.0), dpi=100)
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig2)
canvas.setParent(qFigWidget2)
canvas.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)

ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
x = np.arange(0, 10.0, 0.1)
ax2.plot(x, x*x)
ax2.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

plotLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
plotLayout.addWidget(canvas)

qFigWidget2.setLayout(plotLayout)
qScrollLayout.addWidget(qFigWidget2)
qScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
qScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

qScrollContents.setLayout(qScrollLayout)

qWidget.show()
exit(qapp.exec_())
```

Comment: There is _way_ too much code here.  You can ask this question using the pyplot interface (without all the embedding boiler plate).  _Why_ do you want to do this?  If just want to move the spines a bit farther there are multiple ways to do that inside of mpl (ex  http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#axisartist-with-parasiteaxes).  If you _really_ want two axes, put them in the same figure and have them share an x-axis (

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks for the axisartist link I hadn't seen that before. Yes I tried subplots with axis sharing and turning labels off on all but the first subplot but wanted the first axis offset - as can be done using axisartist

Comment: Most matplotlib examples use pyplot. I can't work out how to use ParasiteAxes using the OO API

Comment: _Most_ `pyplot.foo()` calls map -> `plt.gca().foo()` -> `ax = plt.gca(); ax.foo()` which hopefully helps to translate the examples in to the OO language.  I would ask a new (succinct) question focusing just on the usage of ParasiteAxes.  It is easier to write example that start with `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and then use the OO interface on `ax` and `fig` to remove many of the gui-dependent details from your questions.

Comment: @tcaswell I'll need more study of the API to fully understand your comments but did manage to work out that you can use pyplot within pyqt4 for plot 'design' then qt4 for rendering. A long example is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654812/matplotlib-show-parasite-axis-using-oo-api